# Aggregate by column and compare the text

Tags: r, data.table

I have two dataframes:

```
   VESSELNO        Equip  
     12234          503
     12234          504
     12234          505
     12234          506
     12231          502
     12231          503
     12231          503
```

other dataframe has following columns

```
    VESSELNO        Equip  
     12234          503
     12234          604
     12234          605
     12234          506
     12231          602
     12231          603
     12231          503
```

I want to calculate count of unique Equip combining both dataframes
We can use `data.table` to group by VESSELNO and get the Equip

```
  dt[,paste(Equip,collapse = ","), by = VESSELNO]
```

How can I then compare unique counts?

```
 VESSELNO         Equip  
     12234        (503,504,505,506,604,605)  = 6
     12231        (502,503,602,603) = 4
```

Comment: library(dplyr)

dt <- dt%>%group_by(VESSELNO)%>%summarise(x = n_distinct(Equip))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `rbind` the two datasets, grouped by 'VESSELNO'
 get the count of `unique` elements with `uniqueN`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(rbind(df1, df2))[, .(Count = uniqueN(Equip)), VESSELNO]
#    VESSELNO Count
#1:    12234     6
#2:    12231     4
```

---

If we are using `aggregate`, then use the anonymous function to get the `length` of `unique` elements

```
 aggregate(Equip ~VESSELNO, rbind(df1, df2), FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
```